# Pasar Datagridview a otro Formulairio

Tags: c#

como puedo enviar un datagridview ya cargado a otro formulario? tengo el siguiente codigo pero el datagridview me aparece como null. el siguiente codigo me convoca el formulario y envia la datagridview

```
private void btnConfirmardeuda_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lblTotalVenta.Text == "0" || lblTotalVenta.Visible == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No hay productos para registrar una deuda");
        }
        else
        {
            DeudasCliente frm = new DeudasCliente(tablaventa, Convert.ToDouble(lblTotalVenta.Text));
            frm.Show();
        }

    }
```

este es el codigo del formulario convocado:

```
public DeudasCliente(DataGridView tabladedudas, double total)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = tabladeudas.DataSource;

    }
```

pero no me carga la tabla en el formulario nuevo

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que haces esto en el `constructor` del form, cuando deberias hacerlo en el evento `Load`

Ademas no se pasa ningun control entre formularios, quizas puede pasar datos

```
public class DeudasCliente
{

    private DataTable tabladedudas;
    private double total;

    public DeudasCliente()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public DeudasCliente(DataTable dt, double total) : this()
    {
        tabladedudas = dt;
        this.total = total;
    }

    public void _Load(...)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = tabladeudas;
    }

}
```

La idea es que puedas conservar los datos para que en eventos del form asignarlos a los controles.

Para el diseñador del form funciona necesitas tenerlos sin parametros